# Run SQL state on many database at the same time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Run SQL state on many database at the same time?

I HAVE DATABASE `A,B,C`,
At the same I want to run the sql statments.

for example:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_test ADD COLUMN col_test  character varying(10);
```

Will do Alter to `A,B,C` at the same time.

I am using `PostgreSQL` .

Did anyone know how to do or write `sql script`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Equivalent-to-quot-use-database-quot-in-postgre-td1904315.html) should give you an answer.

> You must specify the database to use
>   on connect; if you want  to use psql
>   for your script, you can use "\c
>   name_database"  à la:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdatabase;
\c testdatabase
CREATE TABLE testtable (testcolumn int);
```

and

> Most MySQL users misunderstand
>   "databases" in postgresql. The closest
>   equivalent in PostgreSQL to a MySQL
>   "database" is a PostgreSQL "schema". 
>   If you expect to be able to run
>   queries that use data from multiple 
>   "databases" you really want to use
>   schema.
>
> See the help for the "psql" command
>   for basic scripting, including the 
>   "\c" command to connect to another DB.
>   For help on an SQL command, run  "\h
>   COMMANDNAME" in psql, or read the
>   manual for that command.

and

> IF you are using the psql command line
>   utility to execute these scripts, 
>   then 
>        \c dbname  will connect to a new database.  However, if you're
>   processing these  scripts some other
>   way, then your app will have to
>   disconnect from the  one database and
>   connect to the other itself (this is
>   what the \c  command tells psql to do)

Comment: It is all there. I quoted most important fragments in my answer.